# How do I set the default sending email account in mail.app using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, apple-mail

I'd like to use Control Plane to change the default sending account in mail.app (preferences->composing->send new messages from) when I switch from a work to a home environment. Control Plane doesn't have an option to do this, and I can't find anything in the mail.app AppleScript dictionary that might work … except, perhaps, "default email account", but that is r/o. Any ideas on ways to do this? I know I can do this message by message, but I want to change the *default*.

Comment: Voting to migrate -- this seems more like a system administration question and not a programming Q&A question.  Also, for anyone else who has never heard of [Control Plane, it's an app found here](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/).

Comment: This is an AppleScript dictionary question, really … but it could be an AppleScript GUI question, too ...

Answer (score 2):

To set the default sending address, you can change the value of the **Send new messages from:** dropdown list in the Mail.app preferences window under the 'Composing' tab.

If you want to use AppleScript to change the sender once you're composing a message, that can be done [using AppleScript as described in this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638711/how-to-set-the-sender-of-the-current-mail-app-outgoing-message-via-applescript/).

Answer (score 0):

In the Composing tab, you can choose to send new messages from the account of the selected mail box. You'll find out that this is sufficient in most cases. There is no way to automate this with AS afaik, except perhaps with GUI scripting.

(I agree that this question doesn't really belong on Stackoverflow).